# window.moveTo() wont go futher than half my screen in firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I generate a window and then on an event I move that window

```js
    popup = open("", 'popup', 'top=' + top + ', left=' + left + ', width=' + width + ',height=' + height + ',toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes');
    popup.moveTo(1440, 0);
```

If I set left to 1440 while opening the window, it appears in the corner of my screen, while when using the function moveTo it sets it in the middle of the screen, even if I increase the value. 
Is it because I have a retina screen, if so how can I fix it ? it only happens in Firefox

Edit, full code using tomer raitz template

```
<button onclick="openWin()">Open "myWindow"</button>
<button onclick="moveWin()">Move "myWindow"</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function moveWin() {
        popup.moveTo(1400, 0);
        popup.focus();
    }

    function openWin() {
        let left = "0px"
        let top = "0px"
        let width = 200;
        let height = 200;
        popup = window.open("", '', `width=${width} height=${height} top=${top} left=${left}`, 'toolbar=no scrollbars=no resizable=yes');
    }
</script>
```

Result in safari [image: Result in safari]
Result in firefox nightly [image]

Comment: Can't repro, also on a retina monitor. What browser are you using? Chrome won't let you go farther than the current monitor (even if you have a multi-monitor setup). So if your popup does touch an edge of your screen, that's its maximum.

Comment: after testing it in different browsers, the problem only appears in firefox, i'll edit the question

Comment: I also tried on FF and it works there for me. They have a bug with the console eager evaluation in v.75 that will make the window move before we actually press enter, but it's been fixed in nightly and I doubt you were typing from the console.

Comment: Weird. I added some screenshots

Comment: Ah `moveTo`! I can repro then. `moveBy` works fine, and `moveTo` indeed is bugged on my retina monitor (jumps directly to the next monitor passed half the screen, and can't go back to the main one...) For a workaround, use `moveBy`. For a solution, open an issue on [their tracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/) if there isn't yet (no time right now to search for it myself sorry).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the window to be in the middle of the screen you needed to calculate the screen size like this :

```
<button onclick="openWin()">Open "myWindow"</button>
<button onclick="moveWin()">Move "myWindow"</button>

function moveWin() {
let screenWidth = 0
let screenHeight = 0;
if(window.outerWidth - window.innerWidth >0){
screenWidth = (window.innerWidth - popup.innerWidth) /2 
}
else{
screenWidth = (window.outerWidth - popup.innerWidth) /2 
}

screenHeight = (window.outerHeight - popup.innerHeight) /2 
  popup.moveBy(screenWidth, screenHeight);
  popup.focus();
}

function openWin(){
let left = "0px"
let top = "0px"
let width = 200;
let height = 200;
 popup = window.open("", '', `width=${width} height=${height} top=${top} left=${left}`,'toolbar=no scrollbars=no resizable=yes');
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I just realized that I wrote "moveBy" instead of "moveTo" in the core of my question. I'm don't want to have to window in the middle of the screen, I'm want to be able to place it anywhere with absolute coordinate. I've now found out that it's a problem only in Firefox, moveTo works as expected in other browsers

Comment: I understand now, and sorry but I can't reproduce your bug (maybe it's on mac only), either way, I think my answer will fix your problem, it's just example for the middle of the screen, you can calculate any coordinate you need and it should behave same on all browsers. if you need I can edit my answer and you could check it again

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h2>NO moveTo() </h2>

  <button onclick="openWin(640,480)">Open "myWindow"</button>

  <script>
    function openWin(w, h) {
      let y = window.outerHeight / 2 + window.screenY - (h / 2)
      let x = window.outerWidth / 2 + window.screenX - (w / 2)
      popup = window.open("", '', `width=${w} height=${h} top=${y} left=${x}`, 'toolbar=no scrollbars=no resizable=yes');
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```